# Do TestFlight uploads / releases interfere with version numbers of Apple App Store releases

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I know (well, believe, based on [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)), that releasing version `2.0.0` of an app on the App Store will prevent me from ever releasing a `1.5.0` version, since version numbers must increase.

I'm in a slightly different situation. I'm actively developing a `1.5.0` version for App Store release, and we have yet to uploaded a `1.5.0` version for either Testflight or the App Store (we used Enterprise certificates for `1.5.0` testing). In the meantime, we're doing concurrent development, and since we're switching to TestFlight for testing, I'm about to deploy my first `2.0.0` version to TestFlight.

Will the existence of a `2.0.0` in TestFlight interfere with the release of a `1.5.0` to the App Store (or possibly to TestFlight, in case we take that route, too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a version available for TestFlight doesn't require an app version entry in App Store Connect.

You can upload builds for older and newer versions and they will appear in the TestFlight area.

If there is a corresponding app version listed in your "versions" on App Store Connect, then the build will also appear there.